# Looking for a comprehensive Combinatorics and Abstract Algebra book/s

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, book-recommendation

I had taken some intro level academic courses in Combinatorics and Abstract Algebra. Sadly, my university doesn't allow to undergrads to partake in the more advance courses, or only at the very end of the bachelors.

Therefore, I'd be thankful to get some recommendations for any comprehensive books in the study fields mentioned above.

I'd heard some good things about Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote, but I don't have enough knowledge to compare them to others.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add the [tag:book-reommendation] tag to your question.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation%2babstract-algebra?tab=Votes) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation%2bcombinatorics?tab=Votes) for plenty of similar questions.

Comment: I personally opine that Dummit and Foote is the best book for self-learning Abstract Algebra. There are other books which might be better for the Galois Theory part like Morandi. Artin's Algebra is very very good but it might not be the best choice for a beginner. There is also Joseph Gallian Contemporary Abstract Algebra which is really good for beginners.

Comment: These fields (combinatorics and abstract algebra) are each too big for any comprehensive treatment in a single book, much less at an introductory level.  For combinatorics I like the fairly thick book *A Course in Combinatorics* by van Lint and Wilson (2nd edition).